# Как поменять цвет action bar?

Tags: actionbar, color, android, design

Как я могу поменять цвет ActionB bar и tab?

У меня используется тема:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">@color/actionbar_color</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/tabs_color</item>-->
  <!--      <item name="android:textColor">#2a4562</item>
        <item name="android:centerColor">#2a4562</item>-->

    </style>
```

а также тулбар вместо action bar:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
             />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Сейчас она зеленого цвета, как я могу поменять его?

Comment: Поправьте разметку, сложно так разобрать. Между кодом и текстом должно быть по 2 переноса строки (2 **Enter**). Чтобы код выделить, каждая его строчка должна иметь 4 пробела в начале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Добавьте вот это в тему:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/red</item>
```

2) Toolbar так сделайте:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
         />
```

3) Теперь ActionBar должен быть красным.